# errors in transformation Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I want to get errors generated by system in Pentaho Kettle and expose it as results in transformation or job, for example i want to get errors of the HL7 input from log and expose it as results in the next step.

Comment: if there will be any error is coming in transformation or job, it will stop execution immediately , you can use write to log step under utility so storing the logs and you can specify the log type as well.

Comment: thank you, but there is not a way to get what is in those errors log and expose it as results for the output of the job??!!

Answer (score 1):

You could you save those results in a temporary csv file that the next step(s) can consume.

If you go with this solution I would recommend:

- Adding a unique jobID or identifier in the file name to ensure that your next step is reading the right file.
- Adding a step at the end that removes old temp files

Comment: your idea is that i store results of a transformation or a job to a csv file that i will used to extract errors that i need for example, actually that's what i understood, but i am asking if there is a way to pass directly those errors in the next step??,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get errors generated by system

You mean like Apache or MySQL errors? If that's the case, you may just point a Pentaho transformation to those files. They usually have a default place like /var/logs/apache2 and that would be pretty easy to read.

The part that's not that easy is if you want to parse those errors into something easier to analyse. For that I would use "load file in memory" and some "regex evaluation" steps to get the data you want out of the raw text.

But, there are better solutions for reading your logs and analyzing errors.
See [LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) for more info or similar products.

Comment: that's sound's good, but actually i found a temporary solution, i added a user java class  to my transformation before the step that i want to get errors.